# Creating user profiles with Parse.com on Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have an app which steps users through creating a profile.

In the first user registration I have:

```
//create new user
ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();
newUser.setUsername(username);
newUser.setPassword(password);
newUser.setEmail(email);
```

These seem to be default user fields.

I am also collecting the user's name, so I do this:

```
ParseObject patient = new ParseObject("patient");
patient.put(patientname, patientname);
```

And then I want to designate a role for this person:

```
ParseACL roleACL = new ParseACL();
ParseRole role = new ParseRole("Patient", roleACL);
role.saveInBackground();
```

Seems okay. Now, on the next screen I ask for their address...do I create a new ParseObject, address?  Or do I add to the ParseObject patient?  Does it matter?

If adding to the Patient object, how would I do that?

Comment: Why not simply collect all information on the user object?

Comment: That way you could also in the next Activity simply do: `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` (assuming the user is logged in by then) and keep adding information. If you insist on having the patient object, you could keep it in a singleton or the like to access the same object and add more information. It would seem strange to create a new object for each piece of information when you want to tie it to the same person/patient?

Comment: I probably missed something in the docs...I was confused about what I could add to currentuser..but it seems I can just add fields to the current user...so, in the login process activity after the login is confirmed, I can add the fields there?  Thanks so much for your help...

Comment: Yes indeed you can :) no problem

Comment: @cYrixmorten I have this code:  String streetaddress = mPatientStreetAddress.getText().toString();
                String city = mPatientCity.getText().toString();
                

                city = city.trim();

                

                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

                currentUser.put(city, city);        ------------------------------------------Correct? Not seeing it in Parse back end...thanks again for your help...

Comment: 1) `currentUser.put("city", city);` first argument should be a string value 2) did you remember to save the user with updated data? `currentUser.saveInBackground()` 3) if still not working, implement the callback and see if there is any errors returned `currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() { .. // see if ParseException e != null })`